# Create A Centered Curved Box Inside a Curved Box

Tags: css, html, curve

I got another css issue that I hope can be quickly remedied.  I'm trying to simply have a curved box of text with one background color, vertically and horizontally centered inside another curved box of another color.  I tried using the border-width attribute for one box, but that only curved the outside border of the box, not the inside border additionally.  I almost have it working, but it is not centering vertically.  This can't be too hard, but I'm hitting a brick wall.  Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div#outer {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#0000FF;
    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
}

#inner{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:95%;
    height:40px;
    margin-top:5px;
    display:block;
    background-color:#ff0000;
    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:24px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:40px;
    text-align:center;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outer"><div id="inner">Centered Text goes here</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahh, I love everybody here!  Adding position:relative, and top:5px fixed the issue!  Thanks Zoltan!

Answer (score 0):

i gave the outer div a padding-top: 5px; and -5px from the height hope this is what you need - http://jsfiddle.net/6Bh5x/1/